# Realtime Calculator

Tags: objective-c, ios

For a school assignment I have been told to make a calculator app, the same as the spotlight calculator. It works in realtime and has no buttons for things to begin.

So far this is my code. It is written in a text field with the event **Editing Did End**. Im pretty sure thats wrong but i can't find an alternative solution. Also i haven't gotten the realtime thing to work so i've kind of reverted to completing the following steps when pressed off the text field.

```
- (IBAction)Didend_Action:(id)sender {
  NSString *list = [Sum_TextField text]; 
  NSArray *listItemsArray = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
  float firstNumber = [[listItemsArray objectAtIndex: 0] floatValue]; 
  NSString *symbol = [listItemsArray objectAtIndex: 1];
  float secondNumber = [[listItemsArray objectAtIndex: 2] floatValue];
  {   
    Calculator* calc = [[Calculator alloc] init];
    [calc setNum1:firstNumber];
    [calc setNum2:secondNumber];
    if ([symbol isEqualToString:@"-"])
    {
        [calc minus];
    }
    else if ([symbol isEqualToString:@"+"])
    {
        [calc add];
    } 
    if ([symbol isEqualToString:@"*"])
    {
        [calc multiply];
    }
    else if ([symbol isEqualToString:@"/"])
    {
        [calc divide];

    }
    [Answer_TextField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [calc answer]]];  
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I know nothing of Objective-C so I doubt I can help with your problem. But I'll help you with asking questions here: C and C++ are different languages, so you shouldn't tag your question with both. But this one question is actually about *another different language*: Objective-C. I fixed up the tags for you this time. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better way to do it would be to implement the UITextViewDelegate protocol methods like `textViewDidChange:`. For example, you could do something like this:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

    NSString *currentText = [textview text];
    NSArray *currentItems = [currentText componenetsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    float result = 0.0;

    //If a valid expression is in the text view
    if([currentItems count] > 2) {

        float num1 = [[currentItems objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
        float num2 = [[currentItems objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
        NSString *operator = [currentItems objectAtIndex:1];

        if([operator isEqualToString:@"+"]) {

            result = num1 + num2;
            answerTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];
        }
        else if([operator isEqualToString:@"-"]) {

            result = num1 - num2;
            answerTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];
        }
        else if([operator isEqualToString:@"*"]) {

            result = num1 * num2;
            answerTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];
        }
        else if([operator isEqualToString:@"/"]) {

            result = num1 / num2;
            answerTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];            
        }
        else{

            answerTextField.text = @"Invalid Operation";
        }
    }
}
```

This would be called every time the user edited the text in the text view. It should work, but I didn't test it out. Make sure that in the header of whatever file this code is in, you do this:

```
@interface yourClassName : yourSuperclass <UITextViewDelegate> {

    //Your instance variables
}

//Your method and property declarations
```

**EDIT:**

Let's say I put the `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView` code in a file called MyClass.m. The file MyClass.m would then look like this:

```
@implementation MyClass

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

    //All the above code goes here
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //INCLUDE THESE LINES
    Sum_TextField.delegate = self;
    Answer_TextField.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

In the header file (MyClass.h), I would put this:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> 

//Note: you don't declare - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView in the header file because you are implementing
//a protocol method.

//MAKE SURE SUM_TEXTFIELD AND ANSWER_TEXTFIELD ARE UITEXTVIEWS NOT UITEXTFIELDS
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *Sum_TextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *Answer_TextField;

@end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just trying this out now :) Thanks for your answer. I'll be sure to come back and let you know what happens

Comment: What do you mean by the second part of your answer. The @interface yourClassName : yourSuperclass <UITextViewDelegate> { }
Is that part meant to go in my ViewController.h where i am writing the code?

Comment: I've added all the code hopefully in the correct places with no errors, with some tweaking :) I run the app now and i insert the sum eg 10 + 3 and nothing happens, nothing comes in the Answer_TextField.
Extremely sorry for my noobieness, but will i have to add more code, like something big im missing to send the information to Answer_TextField

Comment: @MaxBouda - I found a couple errors (they are on my part as I did not tell you this info). 1. Did you connect the IBOutlets? See my updated answer for the other errors.

Comment: Yep, i created them by dragging the textfield with Control+drag into the .h

Comment: So the errors are: you made the answer and sum textfields of type UITextField instead of **UITextView**. Also, you didn't set their delegates to self like in my updated answer. Both these errors were my fault though because I didn't tell you. Sorry.

Comment: Awesome! It worked perfectly. Can I just say thank you so much for your help. Please tell me if there is anyway I can rep you up or something :P THANK YOU !

Comment: No problem. And you don't need to go "rep me up" other then accepting this as the answer, but thanks for offering :)!